# Replacement for TVR 10561 varistor

Tags: power-supply, varistor, mov

I am trying to repair the power supply of my PS4. It looks like the fuse has blown out with the **TVR 10561** varistor. I can't find this varistor online and I am looking for a replacement.

The TVR 10561 data sheet is here: http://www.konkurel.ru/thinking/en-TVR.pdf

The best replacement I could find is https://in.element14.com/littelfuse/v56za3p/metal-oxide-varistor-35-vac/dp/1612088

Does it look like a good replacement? Did I miss some important value?